# Allowing logged in users to create custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types, user-access

I'm looking to create a site with a wide array of user contributed content.  I have strong experience in programming, and I'm evaluating Wordpress for the task.

My question:
Having created a custom post type, can I allow a broad array of users (not necessarily per-approved or know to me) to create and manage their own instances of that custom post type?
What's the best way to go about this?
Is there a front end for that creation, or do they need access to the admin?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your question is in a pretty broad range, therefore I'm close voting as _non constructive_ - there's no final answer/solution. Ad question) You should simply check the source (click SVN-button in wp.org/extend/plugins) of some of the post from front end plugins to get a clue on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right - so there are some plugins that do this.
Some are focused on saving admins the trip to the backend.

I needed something that kept users out of the backend entirely, but allowed them to contribute custom posts.  I'm going with [wp-user-frontend](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-user-frontend/) and so far, it's doing the trick.